# hiding elements in contact form

Tags: jquery, select, hide, onchange, if-statement

Regarding hidden divs in a contact form...

The `else` in "select2" and "select3" JavaScript is not written correctly and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Using jQuery, I have something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#select1").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "retouching" ) {
        $("#hide1").slideDown("fast");
    } else {
        $("#hide1").slideUp("fast");  
    } 
});

$("#select2").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "fashion" || $(this).val() == "beauty" || $(this).val() == "product" || $(this).val() == "architectural") {
        $("#hide2").slideDown("fast");
    } else {
        $("#hide1").slideUp("fast") || $("#hide2").slideUp("fast"); 
    }
});
$("#select1").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "photography" ) {
        $("#hide3").slideDown("fast");
    } else {
        $("#hide3").slideUp("fast");
    } 
});

$("#select3").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "fashion" || $(this).val() == "beauty" || $(this).val() == "product") {

        $("#hide4").slideDown("fast");
    } else {
        $("#hide4").slideUp("fast") || $("#hide3").slideUp("fast");
    }
});
$("#select1").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "studio" ) {
        $("#hide5").slideDown("fast");
    } else {
        $("#hide5").slideUp("fast");
    }    
});
});
</script>
```

Since there are two "hides" in select2 and select3, I'm having trouble hiding both of them if user decides to pick something else from select1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#hide4").slideUp("fast");
$("#hide3").slideUp("fast");
```

instead of

```
$("#hide4").slideUp("fast") || $("#hide3").slideUp("fast");
```

Answer (score 0):

What is this supposed to do?

```
$("#hide1").slideUp("fast") || $("#hide2").slideUp("fast");
```

It (and similar code) should probably be:

```
$("#hide1").slideUp("fast");
$("#hide2").slideUp("fast");
```

Comment: thank you @oded & @marek, I started with your suggestion but it didn't work, which is why I added the "II". the problem lies in hiding "hide2" in addition to "hide1". if I show "hide 1 & 2", and then try to select a different option from "select1", "hide1" disappears but not "hide2".

Comment: @zee - You need to look at the rest of your code again. Make sure the right things happen on the selection of a different option (you may need to _unhide_ the formerly _hidden_ divs.

Comment: is the "else" js not the proper way to unhide the divs?